# Missing required parameters for [Route: editoffice]

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this Editform in my office page the problem is when I press the edit button it says this

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: editoffice] [URI: building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)
```

Routes

```
Route::get('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');
Route::post('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@update')->name('editoffice');
```

Building.blade.php

This is the code for the edit button

```
<a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

OfficeController.php

```
    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $office_id = $request->get('office_id');
    $office = Office::find($office_id);
    return view('editoffice')->withOffice($office)->with('id',$id);

    }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $office = Office::find($id);
        $office->name =$request->officename;
        $office->floor = $request->floor;
        $office->update();
          \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Updated successfully!');
         return redirect()->back();

    }
```

editoffice.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('title', 'Create an Office')
@section('content')

{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', $id], 'class' => 'form')) !!}
<div class="container">

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('Office Name') !!}
                {!! Form::text('officename', $office->name,        array('required',
                          'class'=>'form-control',
                          'placeholder'=>'Office Name')) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('Office Floor') !!}
                {!! Form::text('floor', $office->floor,        array('required',
                          'class'=>'form-control',
                          'placeholder'=>'Office Floor')) !!}
            </div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Update Office',
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}


     <a href="{{ route('building', ['id' => $id] ) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>



</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Please show the `editoffice.blade.php` view.

Comment: There have a look @AlexeyMezenin

Answer (score 2):

Change the form to:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', [$id, $office->id]], 'class' => 'form')) !!}
```

Also, change the `edit` and `update` methods to:

```
public function edit($id, $office_id) {
    $office = Office::find($office_id);
    return view('editoffice', compact('office', 'id'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id, $office_id)
```

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj you have another issue, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)    it show this one dunno why its a non object @Alexey Mezenin    :(

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj but you're using the `$office` variable in the view. Make sure it's not `null`. Or use any other variable you use to pass the office ID. The point is you need to pass it as the second parameter.

Comment: What do you mean @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj I mean you're getting this error because `$office` is `null`. But you pass the `$office` variable to the view. It's not related to the original question, but if you can't handle this by yourself, please show results for `{{ dd($office) }}`

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj if you've changed the controller method as I've shown, add `dd($office_id)`. Then go back and click `Edit office` link again. What does it show?

Comment: Ya I did use this public function edit(Request $request, $id, $office_id) @Alexey Mezenin it shows null

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj then go back, refresh the page and look into the source HTML code. Please show what HTML is generated for the link you click. It should look something like this `<a href="building/2/offices/8/edit">`

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj that's ok. Please change edit and update method as I've shown in the updated answer. What does `dd($office_id)` show now?

Comment: I changed the edit and update methods as you've shown @Alexey Mezenin it shows Undefined variable: office_id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj this can't show `Undefined variable` error: `public function edit($id, $office_id) { dd($office_id); }`

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj ok, then now, if you remove `dd()` and copy paste the `edit` method from my answer, it should work.

Comment: Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)    what is this? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj it's the next error you have. It happens when you're trying to use an array as a string. Try to change it to `'route' => ['editoffice', $id, $office->id]`. If you still get the same error, please show what does `{{ dd($office) }}` show now in the view.

Comment: Thanks it works but error shows when I click update: Creating default object from empty value @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj put `dd($office);` after `find($id);` in the `update()` method. Is it an object or `null`?

Comment: it says "2"   @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj it can't say 2. Please reread my previous comment. It will be `null` or an object.

Comment: sorry, it says "null" @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj try `'route' => ['editoffice', $id, $office->id]`, then `'route' => ['editoffice', [$id, $office->id]` and then `'route' => ['editoffice', ['id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id]` until `dd()` in the `update()` method will return an object and not `null`

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd options shows this  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)     so I removed the bracket of [$id and it shows null @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: How to fix this? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Just add `]` to the end for 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', ['id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id]], 'class' => 'form')) !!}    like this? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Array to string conversion again @Alexey Mezenin
`{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', ['id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id], 'class' => 'form'])) !!}`

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj you didn't add `]` as I've said. `{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', ['id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id]], 'class' => 'form')) !!}`

Comment: not working but I tried this `{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', 'id' => $id, 'office_id' => $office->id], 'class' => 'form')) !!}` and put `dd($request->all());`  in updatefunction and it show `array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "IsPYZjDvvSSFVkhYGRBBohVHqao3zWcrEEVzqbNw"
  "officename" => "Software SMDTC Lab Training Rooms"
  "floor" => "1st Floor"
]`    @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj one of these 3 ways would generate `<form action="http://example.com/building/2/offices/3/edit" ....`

Comment: I tried those but either of this will show, Array to String conversion or the result is null @Alexey Mezenin